# Erlang Frontend

Tags: erlang, frontend, distributed-computing

I am building an erlang environment which is managing a single app distributed across the networks running Linux.

Any thoughts on what will be the best way to build a frontend such as in VB.Net or CSharpe for this server. I guess the main thought is if Erlang can be coupled with a GUI frontend.

Does anyone have experience building a highly interactive frontend for Erlang?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955370/application-architecture)

Comment: It's a duplicate, but I don't think it answers what he's looking for. 
"I guess the main thought is if Erlang can be coupled with a GUI frontend." I'm also interested in seeing an example of how you couple a user interface with an erlang server.

Answer (score 3):

[WxWidgets](http://www.idiom.com/~turner/wxtut/wxwidgets.html) is one way to write a user interface with Erlang. You can integrate the GUI directly with your Erlang application without needing to communicate with an external process.

Comment: I will have to add streaming data and significant interactivity so I was interested in using an environment like c sharpe. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Can Erlang be used with a graphical front end written in some other language? Yes, absolutely. In fact, *any* turing-complete language can be used as a back end and *any* turing-complete language can be used as a front end.

You will probably want to use sockets to connect your back-end code to your front-end code, and you'll need to do a lot of thinking about what logic belongs in the front-end and what belongs in the back.

A common front end that I see used with Erlang is a web application. The Erlang code runs a webserver ([Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org) and [Cowboy](http://ninenines.eu) are popular) and also all the back-end logic. The webserver serves up the HTML/CSS, images, and JavaScript that forms the interface and front-end logic. Even if you're not interested in a web application, it may help your design process to think of that kind of code separation.